# PHP $_GET and .htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I know this is probably a common question and has been asked before but .htacess looks foreign to me and I can't seem to get this to work from looking at previous questions.

I have a index script that searches and the syntax is:

```
.../listing/?field=property_type&query=retail
```

I simply want to rewrite this to:

```
.../listing/{field}/{query}
```

One other catch, I have some fields that are boolean.. for example:

```
.../listings/?forlease=1
```

So in this case I just use `isset()` but would like to rewrite this to:

```
.../listings/forlease/
```

Thanks for your help as always! Stack Overflow rocks!

### **EDIT:**

I see some good answers but completely what I'm looking for:

**User requests:** `.../listing/property_type/retail/`

**Apache rewrites to:** `../listing/?field=property_type&query=retail`

**Script sees:** `$_GET['field']='property_type'` & `$GET['query']='retail'`

In the case of the boolean (all booleans will have only one Dir):

**User requests:** `.../listing/forlease/`

**Apache rewrites to:** `../listing/?forlease=1`

**Script sees:** `$_GET['forlease'] = 1`

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you actually want to rewrite FROM `/field/query` TO `/?field=...&query=...`? Since, you probably don't have actual `field` and `query` folders...

Comment: yep.. right now the script works using ".../listing/?field=property_type&query=retail" I want it to be more SEO freindly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .htaccess you can have a couple of simple rules:

```
RewriteRule ^.*/listings/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-z0-9_]+)$ /listing/?property_type=$1&query=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^.*/listings/forlease/$ /listing/?forlease=1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

If your webserver is Apache, then you can use mod_rewrite.

Check out : http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html =)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^.*/listing/([^/]*)/?$ listing/?$1=1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*/listing/([^/]*)/?(.*)$ listing/?property_type=$1&query=$2 [NC,L]
```

Try this, first checks for a single condition (http://...listing/forlease), otherwise rewrites to (http://...listing/field/query)

You might want:

```
RewriteRule ^.*/listing/([^/]*)/?$ listing/?$1=1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*/listing/([^/]*)/?(.*)$ listing/?property_type=$1&query=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

To keep any additional parameters in the query string.